# Открытие файла во внешней программе

Tags: python, subprocess

Есть код открытия изображения в стандартной программе линукс

```
import os
import subprocess

image_unpack = '/usr/share/applications/xviewer.desktop'
file_path = '/home/user/image.jpeg'
subprocess.run([image_unpack, file_path])
```

Но почему-то при попытке это сделать выкидывает ошибку

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/applications/xviewer.desktop'
```

Comment: `xviewer.desktop` это не программа, а текстовый файл с описанием того, как запускать программу (и xviewer не является «стандартной программой», в линуксе в принципе не существует понятия «стандартная программа»)

Comment: А вообще, когда в контексте линукса ведут разговоры про «стандартные программы», то обычно имеют в виду что-нибудь вроде [xdg-open](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xdg-utils_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#xdg-open)

Comment: @andreymal по поводу "стандартных програм" - извиняюсь, не правильно выразился. А сама программа не текстовой файл, он дает возможность просматривать различные файлы, в том числе и изображения. Если не брать в учет эту программу, тоже самое выкидывает на любую другую, которая умеет открывать изображения.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142700/discussion-on-question-by-krolaper-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.